# Monaca Push Debug App

Tags: ios, cordova, debugging, push-notification, monaca

I am working on an app using Monaca where I need to be able to push notifications to users of the app.  I tried getting the monaca push back-end working, and that wouldn't work, the app didn't register.  I then moved to using the standard cordova plugin, so I can push directly from my servers, without using monaca's back-end.  when I call the init function, normally a register event will fire, this works fine when I build the app.  However I very much want to get the custom debugger working, I am able to build the custom debugger, and I see the plugin properly installed.  Also the init function gets called, as soon as it is called I get the standard IOS security alert to grant the app permission, however the register event is not fired, therefore I am unable to get the device ID to push to the custom debugger app.  Has anyone been able to use push notifications with the custom debugger application?

Best,
Peter

(https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push)

P.S, i calls to set the badge count setApplicationIconBadgeNumber works fine in the debugger.  I think this is something simple, maybe with the certs?  I dont get any errors fired, no notifications no clues using the standard debugger, how can I hunt down what the issue is?

Answer (score 0):

I can get it work using ngCordova, which is AngularJS integration.
http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/pushNotifications/

Then, inject it like

```
    var app = ons.bootstrap('myApp', ['onsen', 'ngCordova']);
```

Get back to me if you need further clarification.

Comment: I installed the plugin and added the code as mentioned here. http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/pushNotifications/   Now I get blank screen when i run the app. If I remove the plugin it works fine. Also, I need to remove ngCordova from bootstrap as well for the app to work again.